# What'w wrong in following mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

Hello Please get me out this.

can not find whats wrong in this query.

```
$pipeline = array(
                        array('$group' => array(
                                 '_id' => '$user_ip_address',
                                 'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
                            ),
                        ),
                        array('$match' => array('camp_id' => $camp_id)),
                    );

        $miui = $this->mongo_db->aggregate('tbl_campaign_analytics', $pipeline);
```

**Responce in error:**
    Array
    (
        [errmsg] => exception: pipeline element 0 is not an object
        [code] => 15942
        [ok] => 0
    )

Please help.....!!!!!!!

Comment: what's the error you encountered, or what is actually the problem with the query? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Can you run the query with just the first aggregation ? Does it return any results ?